# Changing applicationId and namespace in build.gradle causes error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app that I need to change the applicationId and namespace in the app/build.gradle file.

When I run the code using the default values, com.example.dealdiligence, the app runs fine but I can not add the app to the Google Play Store.

I did some research and found that I need to have a unique value for the applicationId and the namespace so I decided to change those values. I ran a script that would change the names in the project but I had to change the values in the app/build.gradle manually.

I also needed to change the google-services.json since the app is connected to Cloud Firestore. I did this.

I also realized that I needed to upgrade my java JDK to version 17 so I did this as well.

I just noticed an error in the app/build.gradle file:

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Build file 'C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\app\build.gradle' line: 4
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin', version: '1.0.0']
Could not find implementation class 'FlutterPlugin' for plugin 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin' specified in jar:file:/C:/Users/Owner/.gradle/caches/jars-9/12cba31fab3a51632261745af12b9ffc/gradle-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/gradle-plugins/dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin.properties.
FlutterPluginJava(0)
```

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin" <<< ERROR IN FRONT OF THIS LINE
    id "com.google.gms.google-services"
} 

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    namespace "com.kane.dealdiligence"
    //compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.kane.dealdiligence"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        // minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

       signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    //implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.3.1"))
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}
```

The error is flagged in the left margin in the plugins section.

I created a new project and changed the namespace and applicationId in the app/build.gradle file to com.kane.dealdiligence and the app would not run. I changed these values back to com.example.dealdiligence and the app runs fine.

So, why can't I change the namespace and applicationId in my app and why am I getting this error in the app/build.gradle file?

Thanks for your help

UPDATE:
I made the changes suggested in the answer but now I am getting this error when I run the app:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.kane.dealdiligence' in C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence\android\app\google-services.json

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 2):

**For a complete application ID change, you can follow these steps:**

1. Start clean from where you haven't changed anything (*recommended*)
2. Activate [rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) package globally

   ```
   flutter pub global activate rename
   ```
3. Rename the `setBundleId`

   ```
   rename setBundleId --value "com.kane.dealdiligence"
   ```
4. Add [change_app_package_name](https://pub.dev/packages/change_app_package_name) package as a dev dependency

   ```
   flutter pub add dev:change_app_package_name
   ```
5. Change the app package name

   ```
   flutter pub run change_app_package_name:main com.kane.dealdiligence
   ```
6. Find for leftovers, search "com.example" in the project folder and replace manually, if any

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought about pulling the code down from github but I am not sure how to do this. I am new to this. I have looked at the github controls but I don't see one that allows me to copy everything from github and replace what I have on my local machine.

Comment: You can just download the GitHub repo as zip, open it on your local and apply these changes. See what files are affected by the changes, and compare it to the repo on GitHub. **Hint:** There might be a necessary folder name change, for example inside `android/app/src/main/kotlin` you can see there's this path: `com/example/dealdiligence`, change that `example` folder to `kane`

Comment: I was able to simply discard all the changes I have made since I had not committed them yet. Thank you for your help. I will follow your instructions on renaming the app and let you know how it goes.